# After upgrade to 5.6 status still shows 5.4.0

Tags: drupal, upgrade

I have CiviCRM for Drupal 7. Just upgraded from 5.4.0 to 5.6.0 via drush. Everything seems OK, including database. Drupal module page shows 7.x-5.6.0. However, CiviCRM status page still thinks that I have 5.4.0 and suggests that I either apply patch to 5.4.1 or upgrade to 5.6.0. I deleted template_c files... How come?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, *never mind*... By the morning it started showing everything correctly. Still curious, where this information is coming from - maybe running `cron` in CRM changed it. I ran `cron` in Drupal - but probably not in CiviCRM

Comment: Did you flush all Drupal caches too?

Comment: You mean, like here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/#clear-cached-files - Delete all files in `sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/`? Yes, I did. Or some other way?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/caching-to-improve-performance/caching-overview

There are tools - such as the Administration menu which gives you an easy link to flush all caches in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I find sometimes upgrading via drush does not run the db upgrades but instead gives a message about being already upgraded. Drush prints the URL that you need, and pasting that to your browser completes the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. In this case I saw that database update *did* run; and when I pasted the URL also told me that db already ran. Probably, just cron did something...